# Horizontal centering without affecting child

Tags: css, magento, center

I have a problem at my [website](http://alis.prod14.magentohotel.dk/) where I'm trying to center the menu.
I would usually add a display: inline-block to the , but that doesn't work in this case, because it ruins the layout of the dropdown.
How else can i center it without ruining the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is giving your nav `<ul>` a width, and then `margin` left and right of `auto`

CSS:

```
#nav_custom {
  //your current styles
  width: 430px; // could be 40% also
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT** I noticed the same issue with the drop-down too. In that case you'll have to play some CSS games to get it working exactly how you wanted.

CSS:

```
.level1 {
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  // position: relative; <- remove this entry
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

We're making the last relative parent the container div, which is the full width of the nav bar. This lets us set the `width` of the drop down to `100%` and position it to the left.

Comment: This would also limit the dropdown to be 430px and i would like it to stay full width :)